# Wordpress widgets using a jquery call

Tags: jquery, wordpress, admin, widget

I am looking to write a widget that the user can select from a drop down menu a list of web badges. On selection the widget code should show a preview of the image. I am struggling to get the jquery working to preview the image in the admin wordpress widget page.

The widget code is as follows

```
    <?php

class Pretty_Badges extends WP_Widget {

  function Pretty_Badges() {
     /* Widget settings. */
    $widget_ops = array(
      'classname' => 'prettybadges',
      'description' => 'Loved By The Pretty Blog');

     /* Widget control settings. */
    $control_ops = array(
       'width' => 250,
       'height' => 250,
       'id_base' => 'prettybadges-widget');

    /* Create the widget. */
   $this->WP_Widget('prettybadges-widget', 'The Pretty Blog Badges', $widget_ops, $control_ops );

    if(is_admin()) {

    $admin_script_url = WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/love-the-pretty-blog/js/prettyblog.js';
$admin_script_file = WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/love-the-pretty-blog/js/prettyblog.js';
if(file_exists($admin_script_file)) {
    wp_register_script('tweet-it-script', $admin_script_url);
    wp_enqueue_script('tweet-it-script');
}
    }


  }

  function form ($instance) {
    /* Set up some default widget settings. */

    $defaults = array('badge' => 'default');
    $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, $defaults ); ?>

  <p>
   <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('badge'); ?>">Select Pretty Badge:</label>
    <p>
    <input type="radio" <?php if (1==$instance['badge']) echo 'checked=checked';?> name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('badge'); ?>" value="1" />
    <img src="http://theprettyblog.com/wp-content/themes/theprettyblogv2/images/logo.gif"/>
    </p>
    <p>
    <select name="image" id="image" class="inputbox" size="1">
        <option value=""> - Select Image - </option>
        <option value="http://theprettyblog.com/wp-content/themes/theprettyblogv2/images/logo.gif">image1.jpg</option>
        <option value="http://theprettyblog.com/wp-content/themes/theprettyblogv2/images/logo.gif">image2.jpg</option>
        <option value="http://theprettyblog.com/wp-content/themes/theprettyblogv2/images/logo.gif">image3.jpg</option>
    </select>

<div id="imagePreview">

</div>

  </p>

  <?php
}
```

and the jquery file

```
    $t = jQuery.noConflict();
$t(function() {

    $t("#image").change(function() {
        var src = $t(this).val();

        $t("#imagePreview").html(src ? "<img src='" + src + "'>" : "");

});    
});
jQuery = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Thanks in adavnce

Comment: This wasn't your question, but you don't really need the $t...noConflict() stuff; you can simply enclose your function as in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/AM2gF/

Comment: As for your question, it would help quite a bit to know what sort of error you're getting, rather than having to go create my own WP plugin to find out. Have you tried Firebug or Firebug lite? Have you tried a breakpoint at var src...? ;)

Comment: theres no error it just does not work

Comment: it more of a problem of activating jquery in the widget admin page

Answer (score 2):

Try this function

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        jQuery('body').on('change', '#image', change_image);    

        function change_image(){

             var $src = jQuery(this).find('option:selected').val();
         jQuery('.image_path').attr('src',$src);

        }   
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to run jQuery with WordPress is

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    // do_stuff();
});
```

Also, you should work with classes instead of IDs, as there can be multiple widget instances on the page.

Here's a [sscce](http://sscce.org):

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'b5f_load_widgets' );

function b5f_load_widgets() {
    register_widget( 'B5F_Example_Widget' );
}    
class B5F_Example_Widget extends WP_Widget {

    private $url;

    function B5F_Example_Widget() {
        $this->url = plugins_url( '/test-me.js', __FILE__ );
        $widget_ops = array( 'classname' => 'example', 'description' => '' );
        $control_ops = array( 'width' => 300, 'height' => 350, 'id_base' => 'example-widget' );
        $this->WP_Widget( 'example-widget','Example Widget', $widget_ops, $control_ops );
        if( is_admin() )
            wp_enqueue_script( 
                    'test-me', 
                    $this->url, 
                    array(), // dependencies
                    false, // version
                    true // on footer
            );
    }    

    function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        echo 'Test';
    }

    function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        return $instance;
    }    

    function form( $instance ) {
        echo "<a href='#' class='test-me'>File to load: {$this->url}</a>";
    }
}
```

And the JavaScript file. Note that we need to add an Ajax listener to fix the  [bug described here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5515/update-widget-form-after-drag-and-drop-wp-save-bug).

```
/**
 * Function to execute onClick
 */
function test_click()
{
    var number = 1 + Math.floor( Math.random() * 5000000 );
    jQuery( this ).html( 'Stack Overflow #' + number );
}

/**
 * For widgets already present on page 
 */
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) 
{
    $( '.test-me' ).click( test_click );
});

/**
 * For fresh widgets dropped on the sidebar
 * https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/37707/12615
 */
jQuery( document ).ajaxComplete( function( event, XMLHttpRequest, ajaxOptions )
{
    // determine which ajax request is this (we're after "save-widget")
    var request = {}, pairs = ajaxOptions.data.split('&'), i, split, widget;
    for( i in pairs )
    {
        split = pairs[i].split( '=' );
        request[decodeURIComponent( split[0] )] = decodeURIComponent( split[1] );
    }
    // only proceed if this was a widget-save request
    if( request.action && ( request.action === 'save-widget' ) )
    {
        // locate the widget block
        widget = jQuery('input.widget-id[value="' + request['widget-id'] + '"]').parents('.widget');

        // trigger manual save, if this was the save request 
        // and if we didn't get the form html response (the wp bug)
        if( !XMLHttpRequest.responseText ) 
            wpWidgets.save(widget, 0, 1, 0);

        // we got an response, this could be either our request above,
        // or a correct widget-save call, so fire an event on which we can hook our js
        else
            jQuery( '.test-me' ).click( test_click );
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

After dragging widget then jquery function enable try this function very help full Thanks ;)

```
jQuery( document ).ajaxComplete( function( event, XMLHttpRequest, ajaxOptions ) {
    // determine which ajax request is this (we're after "save-widget")
    var request = {}, pairs = ajaxOptions.data.split('&'), i, split, widget;
    for( i in pairs ) {
        split = pairs[i].split( '=' );
        request[decodeURIComponent( split[0] )] = decodeURIComponent( split[1] );
    }
    // only proceed if this was a widget-save request
    if( request.action && ( request.action === 'save-widget' ) ) {
        // locate the widget block
        widget = jQuery('input.widget-id[value="' + request['widget-id'] + '"]').parents('.widget');

        // trigger manual save, if this was the save request 
        // and if we didn't get the form html response (the wp bug)
        if( !XMLHttpRequest.responseText ) 
            wpWidgets.save(widget, 0, 1, 0);

        // we got an response, this could be either our request above,
        // or a correct widget-save call, so fire an event on which we can hook our js
        else
           jQuery('body').on('change', '#image', change_image);    

           function change_image(){
            var $src = jQuery(this).find('option:selected').val();
         jQuery('.image_path').attr('src',$src);

        } 
    }
});
```